# Package fontspec Error: The font "FontAwesome" cannot be found

Tags: xetex, fontawesome, docker

I have a simple latex document like this:

```
\documentclass{hijiangtao-resume}

\usepackage{zh_CN-Adobefonts_external}
\usepackage{linespacing_fix}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

\name{蒋强}
\contactInfo{(+86)156666666}{demo@gmail.com}{https://github.com/demo}{}

\section{教育经历}

\datedsubsection{\textbf{中国药科大学},信息管理与信息系统,\textit{本科}}{2009.09 - 2013.06}

\end{document}
```

when I tried to compile the document using this command:

```
xelatex demo.tex
```

this is the full log like this:

```
/app/output/2023/7/92/26/4 # xelatex demo.tex
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./demo.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-05-15>
(/opt/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/hijiangtao-resume.cls
Document Class: hijiangtao-resume 2015/05/25 An elegant Résumé class
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xltxtra/xltxtra.sty
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifxetex.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def)))
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/realscripts/realscripts.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/metalogo/metalogo.sty
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)))))
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xifthen/xifthen.sty
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifmtarg/ifmtarg.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesome.sty
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesomesymbols-generic.
tex)
kpathsea: Running mktextfm FontAwesome
/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation  for FontAwesome.
/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update ?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input FontAwesome
This is METAFONT, Version 2.71828182 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded base=mf)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf FontAwesome
! I can't find file `FontAwesome'.
<*> ...r; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input FontAwesome

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...r; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input FontAwesome

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: FontAwesome.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input FontAwesome' failed to make FontAwesome.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.


! Package fontspec Error: The font "FontAwesome" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...

l.46

?
```

this is the class file `hijiangtao-resume`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{hijiangtao-resume}[2015/05/25 An elegant Résumé class]
\LoadClass[11pt]{article}

% disable indent globally
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
% some general improvements, defines the XeTeX logo
\RequirePackage{xltxtra}
% use xifthen
\RequirePackage{xifthen}
% use fontawesome
\RequirePackage{fontawesome}
% use xcolor for customizing color
\RequirePackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
% loading fonts
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
% Main document font
\setmainfont[
  Extension = .otf ,
  UprightFont = *-regular ,
  BoldFont = *-bold ,
  ItalicFont = *-italic ,
  BoldItalicFont = *-bolditalic
]{texgyretermes}

\RequirePackage[
    a4paper,
    left=0.7in,
    right=0.7in,
    top=0.50in,
    bottom=0.5in,
    nohead
]{geometry}

\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\setlist{noitemsep} % removes spacing from items but leaves space around the whole list
%\setlist{nosep} % removes all vertical spacing within and around the list
\setlist[itemize]{topsep=0.25em, leftmargin=1.5pc}
\setlist[enumerate]{topsep=0.25em, leftmargin=1.5pc}
\RequirePackage[super]{nth}

\titleformat{\section}         % Customise the \section command 
  {\Large\scshape\raggedright} % Make the \section headers large (\Large),
                               % small capitals (\scshape) and left aligned (\raggedright)
  {}{0em}                      % Can be used to give a prefix to all sections, like 'Section ...'
  {}                           % Can be used to insert code before the heading
  [\titlerule]                 % Inserts a horizontal line after the heading
\titlespacing*{\section}{0cm}{*1}{*1}

\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\large\raggedright}
  {}{0em}
  {}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0cm}{*1}{*0.5}

\newcommand{\datedsection}[2]{%
  \section[#1]{#1 \hfill #2}%
}
\newcommand{\datedsubsection}[2]{%
  \subsection[#1]{#1 \hfill #2}%
}
\newcommand{\datedline}[2]{%
  {\par #1 \hfill #2 \par}%
}

\newcommand{\name}[1]{
  \centerline{\Huge\scshape{#1}}
  \vspace{1.2ex}
}

\newcommand{\contactInfo}[4]{
  \centerline{\sffamily\large{\ {#1} \textperiodcentered\ \ {#2}}
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#3}}%
      { } % if {#3} is empty
      {\textperiodcentered\ \ {#3} } % homepage, no space before \text...
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#4}}%
      { } % if {#3} is empty
      {\textperiodcentered\ \ {#4} }
  }
  \vspace{0.7ex}
}

\newcommand{\role}[2]{
  {\par \textit{#1} ~ #2 \par}
  \vspace{0.5ex}
}
```

I have already install the package fontawesome5 fontawesome, why still shows this error? Am I missing something? this is how I install these package:

```
tlmgr install fontawesome fontawesome5
```

BTW, my build environment is come from [`kjarosh/latex:2023.1-small`](https://github.com/kjarosh/latex-docker) docker image. This is the fontawesome package folder looks like:

```
/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public # pwd
/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public
/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public # ls
fandol        fontawesome   fontawesome5  fonts-tlwg    lm            lm-math       philokalia
/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public #
```

I did not found the font using this command:

```
/app/output/2023/7/92/26/4 # fc-list|grep "FontAwesome"
/app/output/2023/7/92/26/4 #
```

Comment: again you are not showing relevant parts of the log, it looks like it is taking a pdftex code path when using xetex, but you have not shown enough of the log to see what files have been used

Comment: check that the fontawesome package installed fontawesome:
        texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome.otf

Comment: I have pasted the full log output. @DavidCarlisle

Comment: I have checked the fontawesome path and it looks like fine.

Comment: you don't need such a long document to test a font. something like this `\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{fontawesome}\begin{document}\faCheck abc\end{document}` is quite enough. Try it with lualatex and xelatex.

Comment: so it is on the xetex path but stopping on `\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}` for some reason